# C# - Moving Cursor Proper Function Windows 8

Tags: c#, cursor, mouse, mousemove, mouseout

I am using this function but SetCursorPos
Private Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Int32, ByVal Y As Int32) As Int32

But i suffered a little problem that when i go to the corners of windows 8. It doesn't invoke side menus, start menus ,  ... etc ..

If anyone knows any importable function 'MouseMove' ? So it would be better support to Smart Screen of Windows8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later I got the a proper opensource library for input simulation on http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/

```
 var   inputSimulator = new InputSimulator(); 
    inputSimulator.Mouse.MoveMouseBy(pixX, pixY);
```

This code work for me .